# 400 (Bad Request) and cannot find manifest.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, heroku

When deploying, heroku tells me that my build succeeds but I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)` for the favicon and the manifest as well as `Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.` Lighthouse tells me that it doesn't link to my manifest.json at all. I'm not sure if these are even related and if that's the case I will make a new question. I am using Reactjs with a node server.

Here is my server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production") {
   app.use(express.static("client/build"));
}

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "./client/public/index.html"));
});


app.listen(PORT, function() {
  console.log(`  ==> API Server now listening on PORT ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Here is the head of my index.html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, 
    shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
</head>
```

[This is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtZlw.png)

[This is my github repo](https://github.com/ajstack/ajstack.github.io)

Let me know if you need more info, if this is a repeat question, or if these problems are unrelated so I can act accordingly.

Answer (score 26):

I had the same problem after deploying my `react-app` on `firebase-hosting`

`manifest.json` and `favicon.ico` gave `400 Bad Request` in `network` tab on google-chrome DevTools

After running `firebase init`,
In case you did not type build when firebase was asking **What do you want to use as your public directory? (public)** 
then you will have to go to `firebase.json` file in your root project folder and manually change hosting -> "public": "build"

It will be some thing like this

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you are `deploying react app on firebase` check [this](https://kaloraat.com/articles/how-to-deploy-create-react-app-to-firebase) and [this's](https://medium.com/@bensigo/hosting-your-react-app-with-firebase-hosting-add1fa08c214) useful also.

Answer (score 1):

In my case go to file public/index.html

Change

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png" />
```

To

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
```

I hope is help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error in my react app build and it's caused by faulty path to manifest.json:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">
```

I fixed it by editing the index.html in **build folder**:

```
href="./manifest.json"
```

to

```
href="manifest.json"
```